# Listen to the input in a while, and start a thread concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, input

1. My main code listens to the input() in a while loop.
2. When some options are given, I need to start some threads and keep listening for the further inputs
3. But, I am not able to listen to the inputs and I am stuck in the threads I started.

```
while not off:
    option = input('1. start server 2. list connected devices 3. list threads 4. stop server >')
    print("Yout option is {}".format(option))
    if option is "1":
        threading.Thread(target=start_server()).start()
        #start_server()
    elif option is "2":
        connected_devices()
    elif option is "3":
        list_threads()
    elif option is "4":
        stop_server()
```

Comment: you should remove () from target=start_server()....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This ( make a object from your new thread first, then remove () from target option and you can not stop your thread like that you wrote! you should write a class for your program or you should get each thread tid and kill them ):

```
import threading

while True:
    option = input('1. start server 2. list connected devices 3. list threads 4. stop server >')
    print("Yout option is {}".format(option))
    if option is "1":
        t = threading.Thread(target=start_server)
        t.start()
        #start_server()
    elif option is "2":
        connected_devices()
    elif option is "3":
        list_threads()
    elif option is "4":
        stop_server()
```

Good Luck ...